# Is it legal to videotape a payment at a business?

Tags: united-states, medical, recording, debt

I went to my doctor's office in order to pay my copay for the federal government's stupidity for following their requirement to get a physician's statement, and I recorded it. Is this legal to do so since HIPAA is to protect a patient, not an employee.

I paid it in pennies because they should be paid by the federal government, not the patient when they're the ones who screwed up because I mentioned to the doctor it was just dotting an i for following their request to the letter.

Comment: You are "punishing" the doctor for the government's stupidity? Are you sure that's wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your state, depends if you recorded sound or just business, depends on if they agreed to you recording or not, depends if the recording was surreptitious or obvious.

Basically, if you have their permission (and you clearly have yours) then its legal. If you don't then state law determines if you need it or not and that law may have different rules between audio and video.

They can, of course, refuse to accept [pennies](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/faqs/Currency/Pages/legal-tender.aspx) as payment.

Comment: It was blatantly obvious because my friend was holding his camera filming, and I explained that I was completely accepting the HIPAA violation which protects the patient, not the medical professionals.